# Keep photos from wrapping despite window size?

Tags: html, css

When my site is full screen, the four pictures show up in a horizontal line.  However, when the window gets smaller, the last picture folds over into the next line. I want all the pictures to stay in a horizontal line no matter what the window size. Any suggestions?

My code:

```css
body {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #d5e0e8;
}

img {
    padding: 2px;
}

h1 {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background-color: #a2b5c1;
    }
    h3{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background-color: #a2b5c1;
}

h4 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background-color: #a2b5c1;
}

ul {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: #6e95ad;
    margin: 25px;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    background-color: #6e95ad;
    margin: 25px;
}

p1 {
    margin: 525;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>
        
    <img src="making%20a%20scene.jpg">
    <img src="sbsn.jpg">
    <img src="mvp.jpg">
    <img src="kevin.jpg">

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <title> My Job </title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <div style="visibility: hidden; height: 0; width: 0">
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <h1> ... ENTERTAINMENT </h1>

            <h2 class="display-3"> Who We Are </h2>

            <p class="lead"> ...is a television production and development company located in S..., California. We create content for television and digital sites such as The History Channel, TLC, Netflix, Discovery, YouTube Red, and many more.

            INE was founded by ... and .... These exectives are responsible for creating shows such as The Office (US), The Biggest Loser, Masterchef, Real Housewives of Orange County, Tabatha‘s Salon Takeover, and several others. </p>

            <p1> <a href="https://www.entertainment.com"> ...Entertainment Sizzle Reel </a> </p1>
        </div>
 
        <div>
            
            <h3> My Role </h3>

            <p> In the summer of 2017, I was hired as a Development Research Associate after working for three months as an intern for .... My role as a research associate varies each work day. My duties include finding and contacting potential talent for digital and reality series, writing and organizing television pitches for networks, deck design, cold-calling experts, and exectuive assitance to ... and .... </p>

        </div>  
        <!-- They are very scary. -->
    
        <span> 
            <h4> Employment Hightlights </h4>
            <ul>
                <li> Transcripting broadcast scripts for <i> Making a Scene with   James Franco </i></li>
                <li> &#36; &#36; &#36; </li>
                <li> Acting as Production Assistant for <i> MVP </i> starring Rob Gronkowski, Andre Ward, Terell Owens, and Julius Randall at CBS Studios</li>
                <li><s> Free Lunch </s></li>
                <li> My roommate was named Morgan Freeman. </li> 
            </ul>
        </span>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try a responsive CSS template, like Bootstrap or Materialize, then insert the images in responsive containers.

Comment: `<img>` elements need to go within the `<body>` tag.  A number of free tools are available to validate your HTML and CSS.  Once your mark-up is valid, research responsive images - StackOverflow has numerous answers written regarding this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are searching the CSS `white-space: nowrap`. The effect is that a line will never break.

HTML

```
<div class="nowrap">
  <img src="making%20a%20scene.jpg">
  <img src="sbsn.jpg">
  <img src="mvp.jpg">
  <img src="kevin.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/2yxcz34d/1/

You could further control the behaviour of the .nowrap container with the CSS `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: visible;`.

Answer (score 0):

So I have this working for you, but first note is you need to remove the  HTML tag to the very top. It should come before the body. For this question I moved it to the top and put everything else below inside of a  tag. Use  for a headline that should appear in the body.

**Working Example**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzZpbe

In the HTML I wrapped the images in a div and gave it the class "gallery-container" and wrapped each image in a div and gave it a calss "gal-image".

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery-container">
  <div class="gal-image">
  <img src="https://i.sdlcdn.com/img/product/descimg/SDL008306056_2.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="gal-image">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71GTFDd4KiL._SX355_.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="gal-image">
  <img src="http://ssl-product-images.www8-hp.com/digmedialib/prodimg/lowres/c03815648.png">
  </div>
  <div class="gal-image">
  <img src="https://assets.logitech.com/assets/65057/k840-mechanical-pdp.png">
  </div>
</div><!-- END GALLERY CONTAINER -->
```

For the CSS I gave the .gallery-container a width of 100% and the .gal-image a width of 25%. This ensures the images will always be 25% of the total .gallery-container width(100%) so all 4 images will always be side-by-side. I gave your images a padding-right of 2px to separate them by 2px but gave the last image a padding-right of 0 so it does not push the container our 2px and cause a horizontal scrollbar.

**CSS**

```
img{
  padding-right:2px;
  max-width:100%;
}

img:last-of-type{
  padding-right:0px;
}

.gallery-container{
   width:100%;
}

.gal-image{
  width:25%;
  float:left;
}
```